# How to set/capture date once to local stroage?

Tags: javascript

how to set the date (now) to localstorage once without it keep on updating ?
I want to get it once, and that's all but still I want to be able to use it because there is another function that is depending on that captured date, the key problem is it keeps on updating how to stop it.

```js
const currentDayChangeNumber = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.day-number')].forEach(day => {
        day.textContent = formatDayNumber(now);
        incrementDayNumber(now);
    });

    // saving the now value to LS //
    localStorage.setItem('date', `${now}`);
}
```

Comment: Check to see if it is already set first, before setting it.  Seems pretty straight forward

Comment: FYI - `.querySelectorAll()` produces an object with a `.forEach()` method. There is no need for the `[...document.querySelectorAll(...)]` gymnastics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage.getItem` returns `null` when the key does not already exist in local storage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem). So you can simply check for that condition before updating the value.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('date') === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('date', `${now}`);
}
```

Depending on the design of the rest of your application, you could also perform this check before calling `currentDayChangeNumber`.

Comment: problem is the date is not static it keeps updating I want to save this current point of time !!